# Launching an url in iOS application instead of launch screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, url, webview

In my IOS web based Application, i need to launch an animation, every time the user opens the application, which has an url, instead of this launch screen below:

```
     - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {



           LaunchViewController * lvc = [[LaunchViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LaunchViewController" bundle:nil];

           glaunchOptions = launchOptions;

           .
           .
           .
}

    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url
    {
        NSLog(@"This is the URL" , url) ;

        BeepViewController * lvc = [[BeepViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BeepViewController" bundle:nil];
        UINavigationController *navVC = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
        if (navVC) {
            [navVC pushViewController:lvc animated:NO];
        }
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        return YES ;
    }
```

the open url function was used to open a page in my application by pressing on a web based button.
my url for example is : name.mobi/app/yyy.html
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Try to read mode about Objective-C: Custom URL Schemes.

You should use this method to handle open app from the URL:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
    // handler code here
}
```

You can use this approach to show screen:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *root = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BeepViewController"]];
self.window.rootViewController= root;
```

To open URL use this snippet:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.path.com"]];
```

Comment: i used this function to open a page from this application from w webView button. so how can i add the launch url to it?

Comment: launch url to the page in iOS application?

Comment: i want to launch my application  with a url, which  contains a small animation, NOT From a Launch Screen

Comment: yes and what is the problem animate appearance of the viewController

Comment: the problem is how to call the url when the app is launched.url should be launched before going inside the app

Comment: First try to describe you're problem correct. And do not change what you ask. Try to write issue clear.

Comment: i have an application, when the user launches the application, i want to open a url link to be displayed instead of the Launch Screen. So instead of launching the Launch Screen when the app begins, i want to launch a URL link,

Comment: You what to open web-view first ?

Comment: its an web based application, it contains a web view where all html pages are displayed, all i want is to display a url before the application takes me to the first web View

Comment: By display you mean open URL ? if yes use [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL]